# Background Image Placement in CSS

Tags: html, css, position

This is a simple question about CSS, but I am not sure I know how to ask it correctly.  Basically, I have an image that I wanted repeated both x and y.  But even though this image is repeated, is it possible to style it as if the image was positioned absolutely?

Take this image here: https://samraines.herokuapp.com/assets/paper-d5baa328bec5b7c9fe4cf98bba88452e.png, and look at it here: https://samraines.herokuapp.com/shows .  This is what I was wanting to use this style on, but was unsure if I could accomplish and "absolute" style due to the image's size.

Clarifying once more, I want the image to repeat, but appear as if it was fixed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "styling as if it was positioned absolutely"? Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/f6th8/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css:

```
.element {
    background-image: url(...);
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: auto;
    background-attachment: fixed; // if you do not want to scroll image with site
}
```

like here http://codepen.io/Chovanec/pen/dkFDp